# SQL group by records only when sum(percentage) < 100 if not display the record as is

Tags: sql, group-by

Trying to perform group by operation where records should be grouped only when percentage is less then 100, if 100 or more it should be kept as is.

Sample Data:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Group by query I am trying is:

```
SELECT ID,SUM(Percentage),SUM(Value)
From table
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select data with <100 and >=100 independently, and the use `UNION BY`:

```sql
SELECT ID, SUM(Percentage), SUM(Value)
  From table
 where Percentage < 100
 GROUP BY ID

UNION ALL

SELECT ID, Percentage, Value
  From table
where Percentage>=100
```

Comment: is there a way to do it in single set i.e. without using union all?

Comment: @APRIL, surely. Added second answer. But I don't recommend using it, unless you have **really** good reason not to use `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution without `UNION ALL`:

```sql
SELECT ID, SUM(perc), SUM(val)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        ID, perc, val, 
        case when perc < 100 then '1' else ROWIDTOCHAR(ROWID) end flag
    From t1)
GROUP BY ID, flag
```

Here we use an artificial grouping indicator. It's equals `'1'` for all rows, that we want to group, and `ROWID` converted to a string for rows that should not be grouped.

***CAUTION:*** This solution created with Oracle in mind, and is not portable. For other DBMS' you'll need to use other hacks to generate grouping indicator.